# Rotating Triangle in WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl

I  am trying to render a 3D rotating triangle, I have made all the necessary changes but my triangle is way out of shape(doesn't look like a triangle). Do you guys know what I am missing here?

edit: I have attached the output, and yes I have tried playing with the vertices and it doesn't do much(as in it doesn't form a triangle)

```js
var canvas;
var gl;

var NumVertices  = 12;

var points = [];
var colors = [];

var xAxis = 0;
var yAxis = 1;
var zAxis = 2;

var axis = 0;
var theta = [ 0, 0, 0 ];

var thetaLoc;

var vertices = [
    vec3(0.5, -0.2722, 0.2886),
    vec3(0.0, -0.2722, -0.5773),
    vec3(-0.5, -0.2722, 0.2886),
    vec3(0.5, -0.5443, 0.0)
]

var vertexColors = [
    [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // black
    [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // red
    [ 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // yellow
    [ 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ]  // green

];

window.onload = function init()
{
    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );
    
    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

    colorCube(); //change this name to pyramid

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
    
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);


    var program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    gl.useProgram( program );
    
    var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor );

    var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(points), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    thetaLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "theta"); 
  
    
    document.getElementById( "xButton" ).onclick = function () {
        axis = xAxis;
    };
    document.getElementById( "yButton" ).onclick = function () {
        axis = yAxis;
    };
    document.getElementById( "zButton" ).onclick = function () {
        axis = zAxis;
    };
        
    render();
}

function colorCube()
{
    quad( 0, 1, 2 );
    quad( 3, 1, 0 );
    quad( 0, 1, 2 );
    quad( 0, 2, 3 );

}

function quad(a, b, c) 
{

    var indices = [ a, b, c];

    for ( var i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i ) {
        points.push( vertices[indices[i]] );

        colors.push(vertexColors[a]);
        
    }
}

function render()
{
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    theta[axis] += 2.0;
    gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, theta);

    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices );

    requestAnimFrame( render );
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="512"" height="512">
Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
</canvas>
   
<br/>

<button id= "xButton">Rotate X</button>
<button id= "yButton">Rotate Y</button>
<button id= "zButton">Rotate Z</button>

<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

attribute  vec4 vPosition;
attribute  vec4 vColor;
varying vec4 fColor;

uniform vec3 theta;

void main() 
{
    // Compute the sines and cosines of theta for each of
    //   the three axes in one computation.
    vec3 angles = radians( theta );
    vec3 c = cos( angles );
    vec3 s = sin( angles );

    // Remeber: thse matrices are column-major
    mat4 rx = mat4( 1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  c.x,  s.x, 0.0,
            0.0, -s.x,  c.x, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );

    mat4 ry = mat4( c.y, 0.0, -s.y, 0.0,
            0.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0,
            s.y, 0.0,  c.y, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );


    mat4 rz = mat4( c.z, -s.z, 0.0, 0.0,
            s.z,  c.z, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

    fColor = vColor;
    gl_Position = rz * ry * rx * vPosition;
} 
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

precision mediump float;
   
varying vec4 fColor;

void
main()
{
    gl_FragColor = fColor;
}
</script>


<script src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/initShaders.js"></script>
<script src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/MV.js"></script>
```

--------------------------------Output---------------------------
Here is the picture of my output, which rotates on all the axis but it doesn't have the shape of a 3d Triangle

[image]

Comment: What does "way out of shape" mean? A triangle is defined by the location of its vertices. you're defining the vertices by hand. Have you tried adjusting those values? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AndyRay - I have updated the post with output

Comment: If you want 3D you need to do [3D math](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-perspective.html). Also please take a look at how I edited the code you posted so it runs. I put the parts in a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). I removed unneeded html. So next time you can post something that works. The other change is you had a size of 4 for position we calling `vertexAttribPointer` and that needed to be 3 otherwise the code got an error "attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just have bad indices in `colorCube`

I change them to this

```
function colorCube()
{
    quad( 0, 1, 2 ); // bottom
    quad( 1, 0, 3 ); // side0
    quad( 1, 2, 3 ); // side1
    quad( 2, 0, 3 ); // side3

}
```

and it seemed to work.

I also changed the way it picks colors for the faces so it just makes each triangle the next color.

```
function quad(a, b, c) 
{

    var indices = [ a, b, c];
    var ndx = points.length % vertexColors.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i ) {
        points.push( vertices[indices[i]] );

        colors.push(vertexColors[ndx]);
        
    }
}
```

Seems to work.

```js
var canvas;
var gl;

var NumVertices  = 12;

var points = [];
var colors = [];

var xAxis = 0;
var yAxis = 1;
var zAxis = 2;

var axis = 0;
var theta = [ 0, 0, 0 ];

var thetaLoc;

var vertices = [
    vec3(0.5, -0.2722, 0.2886),
    vec3(0.0, -0.2722, -0.5773),
    vec3(-0.5, -0.2722, 0.2886),
    vec3(0.5, -0.5443, 0.0)
]

var vertexColors = [
    [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // black
    [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // red
    [ 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // yellow
    [ 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ]  // green

];

window.onload = function init()
{
    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );
    
    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

    colorCube(); //change this name to pyramid

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
    
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);


    var program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    gl.useProgram( program );
    
    var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor );

    var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(points), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    thetaLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "theta"); 
  
    
    document.getElementById( "xButton" ).onclick = function () {
        axis = xAxis;
    };
    document.getElementById( "yButton" ).onclick = function () {
        axis = yAxis;
    };
    document.getElementById( "zButton" ).onclick = function () {
        axis = zAxis;
    };
        
    render();
}

function colorCube()
{
    quad( 0, 1, 2 ); // bottom
    quad( 1, 0, 3 ); // side0
    quad( 1, 2, 3 ); // side1
    quad( 2, 0, 3 ); // side3

}

function quad(a, b, c) 
{

    var indices = [ a, b, c];
    var ndx = points.length % vertexColors.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i ) {
        points.push( vertices[indices[i]] );

        colors.push(vertexColors[ndx]);
        
    }
}

function render()
{
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    theta[axis] += 2.0;
    gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, theta);

    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices );

    requestAnimFrame( render );
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="512"" height="512">
Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
</canvas>
   
<br/>

<button id= "xButton">Rotate X</button>
<button id= "yButton">Rotate Y</button>
<button id= "zButton">Rotate Z</button>

<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

attribute  vec4 vPosition;
attribute  vec4 vColor;
varying vec4 fColor;

uniform vec3 theta;

void main() 
{
    // Compute the sines and cosines of theta for each of
    //   the three axes in one computation.
    vec3 angles = radians( theta );
    vec3 c = cos( angles );
    vec3 s = sin( angles );

    // Remeber: thse matrices are column-major
    mat4 rx = mat4( 1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  c.x,  s.x, 0.0,
            0.0, -s.x,  c.x, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );

    mat4 ry = mat4( c.y, 0.0, -s.y, 0.0,
            0.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0,
            s.y, 0.0,  c.y, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );


    mat4 rz = mat4( c.z, -s.z, 0.0, 0.0,
            s.z,  c.z, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

    fColor = vColor;
    gl_Position = rz * ry * rx * vPosition;
} 
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

precision mediump float;
   
varying vec4 fColor;

void
main()
{
    gl_FragColor = fColor;
}
</script>


<script src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/initShaders.js"></script>
<script src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/MV.js"></script>
```

If you want perspective 3D instead of orthographic 3D you'd probably use a [perspective matrix](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-perspective.html)

Comment: that looks right, I need it to be perspective 3D. I checked the link you attached and I was not able to achieve the result, what changes are required?